# How to debug a website while running IIS 7?

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7, .net, debugging

I am running iis7 on my windows machine for testing purposes. Now I need to have access to the debugger so when something happens I can walk through it.

Yet when I put debug lines on my site nothing happens. So I am guessing I need more stuff setup to make debugging to work.

Everything is on the same machine. I have iis 7 on the same machine setup and I have Visual studios setup on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have debugging enabled in your web.config.

```
<compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true">
</compilation>
```

...and I'm assuming you're running it through the debugger in vs.net, right?

Comment: Ya I have debug set to true and I am in debug mode. But I am typing in my ipaddress to connect to my site. So don't know how that effects things

Comment: How can you be in debug mode if you're typing in your IP address? Aren't you running this through visual studio with the build in webserver?